# Partition to use entire disk

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, disk-usage

I am very new to Linux, Ubuntu and this forum.  Is it possible to install Ubuntu (19.04 or 19.10) so that the entire disk is used?  I just ran into a disk space error extracting a theme to /usr/share/themes. Can the entire disk be used like in windows so I never have disk space issues? I am currently using 19.10.  Do I have to reinstall to make this happen?

EDIT: I guess I didn't really know what to ask.  I needed to know how to set up the partition table to use the entire disk.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace this website explained it very well and included other info I needed to know.

Comment: Yes you can use an entire disk for an install; however note Ubuntu 19.10 hasn't been officially released yet (due 17 October) and is off-topic on this site until it's formal release. For 19.10 questions, because it's ubuntu+1, you need to use Ubuntu Forums, or IRC, or for this site wait until after official release. https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic    You can also expand your partition to use entire disk, but as you're using 19.10 - that question currently is off-topic here

Comment: The easiest way is to boot a live system (such as your Ubuntu install media) and expand there.  As the location where `grub` points will move - you may need to re-write/re-install the grub MBR (`grub-install`) but it may not be required depending on setup....

Comment: I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 19.04 and created my own partiton table using this site as a guide https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace

Answer (score 0):

As you said, doing a fresh install of Ubuntu 19.04 and creating a new partition table will fix the issue.